# Android app Shortcuts : How to Debug the flow of Android app shortcut in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-appshortcut

Currently I am working with Android app shortcuts, my shortcut initially making some service request from the presenter of the launching activity. This service request is happening before the UI comes in to screen.

Now the issue is how I will debug the initial flow of the Android app shortcut.
Can anyone help me with this

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in the first place, incl. elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/). Majority of newbies' questions are not unique and has already been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using static app shortcuts. Since it requires to fetch some information before creating shortcuts you might want to use Dynamic shortcut.

Refer : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

Another option can be disabling the static shortcuts by default, and then enable them once you have necessary information.

Good luck!